# Excel split column by words

Tags: excel

[image]
It seems there are some formatting problem here, I can't get the table format correct, so I attached a screenshot on preview.

Comment: Can you please improve the formatting of your question to make it more clear to understand.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri I attached a screenshot on preview, don't know why it works on preview but after you save the question it has some formatting problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B1 write this formula and drag it to the right and down.

```
=MID($A1;COLUMNS($B$1:B1);1)
```

Change semicolon to comma first, if your Excel version uses commas instead.

[image]